# Is there any tool to create dependency graphs for GitHub private repositories mainly written in Python -only showing the private dependencies?

Tags: python, github, dependencies

I'm working in a company that has a couple of private repositories - all of them mainly written in Python. 
Each repo has at its root a *requirements.txt* file. 
We are interested in listing the dependencies and dependents for each repository, not the public ones but just our private dependencies and dependents.
Assume for example the *requirements.txt* file for `our_private_package1` looks like this:

```
public_package1
public_package2
public_package3
our_private_package2
our_private_package3
```

Also assume there is another package `our_private_package4` which has the following *requirements.txt* file:

```
public_package2
public_package4
our_private_package1
```

So we would like to build a dependency graph in which we could see the following for `our_private_package1`:
Dependencies:

- our_private_package2
- our_private_package3

Dependents:

- our_private_package4

Ideally, we would like to visualize the dependencies with a graph.

2 notes:

- [GitHub's solution](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/understanding-your-software-supply-chain/about-the-dependency-graph) is not suitable here for 2 reasons. First, it
  only shows public dependencies. Also it does not determine the
  dependents of private repositories (whether the dependents are public
  or private).
- Dependencies should no be transitive. With the example above, `our_private_package2` should not be listed as dependent for `our_private_package4` (although we
  should see in a visual representation a path from
  `our_private_package2` to `our_private_package4`, with a directed branch from `our_private_package2` to `our_private_package1` and
  another branch from `our_private_package1` to `our_private_package4`).

If there is no available tool for such kind of problem, I would like at least some guidance how to do it with some Python code (almost sure it's feasible).

Comment: Why not just use [Github's solution](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/understanding-your-software-supply-chain/about-the-dependency-graph)?

Comment: It only shows public dependencies. Also it does not determine the dependents of private repositories (whether the dependents are public or private).

Comment: Can/should dependencies be transitive ? I mean, if `our_private_package5` depends on `our_private_package4`, should it be listed as dependent for `our_private_package1` ? I had a similar problem recently, and developed something custom (using just Python's dicts, lists and sets, exporting to json and graphviz).

Comment: I prefer dependencies not to be transitive (although if they are transitive it still provides useful information). I hope I've clarified what I'm looking for in the edited question. I've also added the clarification I've made in my first comment following @0x263A 's question.

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentionned in the comments, I had a similar need. I solved it using a similar approach than this one :

```
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import List, Tuple, Dict


def main():
    requirements_file_content_per_package = {
        "our_private_package1": """\
public_package1
public_package2
public_package3
our_private_package2
our_private_package3
        """,

        "our_private_package2": """\
public_package2
public_package4
our_private_package1
        """
    }

    private_packages_names = ["our_private_package1",
                              "our_private_package2",
                              "our_private_package3",
                              "our_private_package4"]

    # process descending dependency
    private_packages_dependencies: Dict[str, Tuple[List[str], List[str]]] = {}
    for private_package_name in private_packages_names:
        requirements_file_content = requirements_file_content_per_package.get(private_package_name, "")
        private_packages_dependencies[private_package_name] = classify_dependencies(requirements_file_content, private_packages_names)

    # display
    for private_package_name, (package_private_dependencies_names, _) in private_packages_dependencies.items():
        print(f"package {private_package_name!r} depends on private {package_private_dependencies_names!r}")

    # process ascending dependencies
    private_packages_dependents: Dict[str, List[str]] = defaultdict(list)
    for private_package_name, (package_private_dependencies_names, _) in private_packages_dependencies.items():
        for package_private_dependency_name in package_private_dependencies_names:
            private_packages_dependents[package_private_dependency_name].append(private_package_name)

    # display
    for private_package_name, package_private_dependents_names in private_packages_dependents.items():
        print(f"package {private_package_name!r} is depended on by private {package_private_dependents_names!r}")


def classify_dependencies(requirements_file_content: str, private_packages_names: List[str]) -> Tuple[List[str], List[str]]:
    private_dependencies: List[str] = []
    public_dependencies: List[str] = []
    for dependency_name in requirements_file_content.splitlines():
        is_private = dependency_name in private_packages_names
        if is_private:
            private_dependencies.append(dependency_name)
        else:
            public_dependencies.append(dependency_name)
    return private_dependencies, public_dependencies


main()
```

It's a bit crude, and I am using very basic Python (strings, lists and sets) but it could be possible to use a directed colored graph instead. Also, the names get very long because I wanted to be descriptive, but I think using a concise defined vocabulary would be better.

As for visualization :

```py
    import graphviz  # installed with pip

    dot = graphviz.Digraph()
    # at first, create all the nodes
    for private_package_name in private_packages_names:
        dot.node(private_package_name)
    # then create the edges
    for private_package_name, package_private_dependents_names in private_packages_dependents.items():
        for package_private_dependent_name in package_private_dependents_names:
            dot.edge(package_private_dependent_name, private_package_name)
    dot.render("deps.gv", format="png")
```

produced `deps.gv.png` :
[image: rendering of the dependencies using Dot (Graphviz)]

Answer (score 0):

4 years old https://github.com/grosser/repo_dependency_graph/ by legendary & hyper productive Michael Grosser from Zendesk does the job